# How to add duplicate Values to a map?

Tags: java, collections

As we all know map doesn't allow duplicate values,but is there a way to add duplicate values to a map.I need to add duplicate Key and Value to a map such as

```
1    A
1    C
1    D
2    D
2    G.
```

When its put to a map it will return only 1    D and 2    G.I have tried google Multimap but having problem with iteration .Is there any possibility to solve this or what approach can be taken to allow duplicate value to a map.

Comment: *map doesn't allow duplicate values* I don't think so.

Comment: *I have tried google Multimap but having problem with iteration*: so, post what you tried, explain what it's supposed to do and what it does instead. Guava's Multimaps work fine.

Comment: instead of storing value, add `List` of values..it may help you storing multiple values for same key.

Comment: @JBNizet yes something like that we good.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the map but define it to hold a list of values for every key...

```
Map<String, List<Points>> myMap = ....
```

now you need to carefully append those values to every key present so you should just do `myMap.put(1, A)` but instead get the value by `1` and if present call `value.add(A)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not add duplicate key values to a `Map`. But you can create a `Map <Key, Collection <Value>>` and add the values to the collection behind key.

Answer (score -1):

if you just need the Multimap for one special case you can simply create a data object like

class Multivalue

String (or Object, whatever) valueOne
   String valueTwo

HashMap Integer, Multivalue map = new HashMap Integer,Multivalue ()